# Understanding Insertion Sort algorithm

Tags: java, insertion-sort

I am learning the mechanics of **Insertion Code**. This is the original **Insertion Code** algorithm as described in several sites:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    int key = a[i];
    int j = i;

    while (j > 0 && a[j-1] > key) {
        swap(a, j, j - 1);
        j--;
    }

    a[j] = key;
}
```

The issue is while learning how it works, I realized that the next code without using a key, does exactly the same:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    int j = i;

    while (j > 0 && a[j-1] > a[j]) {
        swap(a, j, j - 1);
        j--;
    }
}
```

My question is, why is they **key** required in the original algorithm? is it needed for some edge cases that the second algorithm doesn't take into consideration? If so, which edge cases would them be?
After some testing the results of both algorithms perform the same amount of swaps, so I can't figure out what is the difference of having to use a key variable.

Comment: It is not required. Semantically, both algorithms are the same. The `key` is the "*current value under observation*" if you so want (`a[j]` in the modified version). The core difference is that the original code fetches the value only once, while the updated version fetches it over and over again.

Comment: Doesn't the second solution look more like a bubble sort but backwards?

Comment: Is your question answered?